# What's the KeyEvent number that is same as Grave Accent

Tags: java, awt, keyevent

I want to get the KeyEvent number of the Grave Accent(To make no ambiguity, the picture is [image] ).

I tried to get it by using **KeyEvent.VK_** but I failed to find it in KeyEvent and hope to get answer from you.

Comment: There isn't one, technically, it's SHIFT+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, there isn't one.

A `~` is (on most keyboards) represented by the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> key.  This is represented by the `KeyEvent.VK_BACK_QUOTE` virtual key and the `InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK` modifier

Comment: Actually what I want to know is the KeyEvent.VK_BACK_QUOTE and I still find it in you answer. Thanks a lot.